# in this Semaphore example ,Is it necessary to lock for refill() and buy()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

in this Semaphore example ,Is it necessary to lock for refill() and buy() ?

the Book said :
The refill() function is performed when the owner of the fictitious vend-
ing machines comes to add one more item to inventory. The entire routine
represents a critical section; this is why acquiring the lock is the only way
to execute all lines.

but I think it is ot necessary to lock for refill() and buy() 
what about your opinion ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from atexit import register
from random import randrange
from threading import BoundedSemaphore, Lock, Thread
from time import sleep, ctime

lock = Lock()
MAX = 5
candytray = BoundedSemaphore(MAX)

def refill():
   # lock.acquire()
    try:
        candytray.release()
    except ValueError:
        pass
    #lock.release()

def buy():

    #lock.acquire()
    candytray.acquire(False)
    #lock.release()

def producer(loops):
    for i in range(loops):
        refill()
        sleep(randrange(3))

def consumer(loops):
    for i in range(loops):
        buy()
        sleep(randrange(3))

def _main():
    print('starting at:', ctime())
    nloops = randrange(2, 6)
    print('THE CANDY MACHINE (full with %d bars)!' % MAX)
    Thread(target=consumer, args=(randrange(nloops, nloops+MAX+2),)).start() # buyer
    Thread(target=producer, args=(nloops,)).start() # vendor

@register
def _atexit():
    print('all DONE at:', ctime())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _main()
```

Answer (score 1):

A lock is absolutely necessary. Perhaps it will help if you changed the code a little to print the number of candies left after each producer/consumer call. Replaced semaphore because all it was doing was keeping a count.

I added

```
numcandies = 5
```

For refill:

```
def refill():
    global numcandies
    numcandies += 1
    print ("Refill: %d left" % numcandies)
```

For buy:

```
def buy():
    global numcandies
    numcandies -= 1
    print("Buy: %d left" %numcandies)
```

Here's the output without locks (which shows data race issue).

```
('starting at:', 'Tue Mar 26 23:09:41 2013')
THE CANDY MACHINE (full with 5 bars)!
Buy: 4 left
Refill: 5 left
Refill: 6 left
Buy: 5 left
Buy: 4 left
Buy: 3 left
Refill: 6 left
Refill: 7 left
Buy: 6 left
('all DONE at:', 'Tue Mar 26 23:09:43 2013')
```

Somewhere between the call of `producer` and the actual update of the `numcandies` counter, we had 2 successive calls to `consumer`.

Without locking, there is no control over the order of who actually modifies the counter. So in the above case, even though `numcandies` was updated to 3 buy `consumer`, the `producer` still has a local copy of 5. After updating, it sets the counter to 6, which is completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's critical section - you have to lock it. Uncomment those commented lines.

`candytray` is a resource for which are threads struggling. There is the rule about independence of tasks: Two tasks are independent if they don't have the same codomain AND first's domain NOT EQUALS second's codomain AND second's domain NOT EQUALS first's codomain. It means that, two tasks only may READ from one memory / variable / etc.

In your case, if `candytray` is implemented as some queue, you don't need to lock, because "writer" puts data on, let's say, left side, and "reader" reads from right side. So, their domains and codomains not equal and that task are independent.
But, if it is not queue, if it is some, let's say heap, then writer's codomain interfere with reader's domain. They are dependent then and you need to lock.

## edit

as you can see, I talked from theoretical aspect, not Python's aspect. But I guess you wanted that.

Answer (score 0):

The [original code](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/python/9780132779371/multithreaded-programming/ch04lev1sec7), from Wesley Chun's book *Core Python Applications Programming* looked like this:

```
def refill():
    lock.acquire()
    print 'Refilling candy...',
    try:
        candytray.release()
    except ValueError:
        print 'full, skipping'
    else:
        print 'OK'
    lock.release()

def buy():
    lock.acquire()
    print 'Buying candy...',
    if candytray.acquire(False):
        print 'OK'
    else:
        print 'empty, skipping'
    lock.release()
```

Without the `lock`, the print statements can become interwoven into unintelligible output. For example, suppose the candy tray is full. Then suppose there is a call to `refill` followed by a call to `buy` such that the lines of code get executed in this order (without the lock):

```
print 'Refilling candy...',

print 'Buying candy...',    

try:
    candytray.release()

if candytray.acquire(False):
    print 'OK'

except ValueError:
    print 'full, skipping'
```

The output would look like this:

```
                   # we start with 5 candy bars (full tray)
Refilling candy... # oops... tray is full
Buying candy...    
OK                 # So now there are 4 candy bars
full, skipping     # huh?
```

That would not make sense, so a lock is required.